How can I create a dynamic form that adds/removes input fields based on user interaction?
I’m working on a form where users need the ability to dynamically add or remove input fields based on their actions. Specifically, I want to create a form that starts with one input field and allows users to add new input fields by clicking an "Add Input" button, and remove the last added input field by clicking a "Remove Input" button.
I’ve tried using JavaScript to add and remove the input fields, but I’m not sure if I’m doing it correctly or if there’s a more efficient way to handle this. Below is the HTML and JavaScript code I’ve written so far.


const addButton = document.getElementById('addInput');
const removeButton = document.getElementById('removeInput');
const inputContainer = document.getElementById('inputContainer');

addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const newInput = document.createElement('input');
  newInput.type = 'text';
  newInput.name = 'inputField[]';
  inputContainer.appendChild(newInput);
});

removeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const inputs = inputContainer.getElementsByTagName('input');
  if (inputs.length > 1) {
    inputContainer.removeChild(inputs[inputs.length - 1]);
  } else {
    alert('At least one input field is required!');
  }
});
<form id="dynamicForm">
  <div id="inputContainer">
    <input type="text" name="inputField[]">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="addInput">Add Input</button>
  <button type="button" id="removeInput">Remove Input</button>
</form>




what does your code do? anything? any errors in the browser console?

Do you need control on your input indexes? For example, <input type="text" name="inputField[0]">?

I will suggest that you create a remove button for each input. Try not to use id's for elements -- they have to be unique, and are not really needed in forms, because form fields can be referred by name.


const form = document.forms.dynamicForm;

form.addEventListener('click', e => {
  switch (e.target.name) {
    case 'add':
      addInput(e.target.form);
      break;
    case 'remove':
      removeInput(e.target);
      break;
  }
});

function addInput(form) {
  let fs = document.createElement('fieldset');
  fs.name = 'input';
  let input = document.createElement('input');
  input.type = 'text';
  input.name = 'inputField[]';
  fs.appendChild(input);
  let button = document.createElement('button');
  button.textContent = '✖';
  button.type = 'button';
  button.name = 'remove';
  button.title = 'Remove input';
  fs.appendChild(button);
  form.list.appendChild(fs);
}

function removeInput(button) {
  let form = button.form;
  if (form.input.length > 1) {
    let fs = button.closest('fieldset[name="input"]');
    fs.remove();
  } else {
    alert('At least one input field is required!');
  }
}
fieldset {
  border: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

button[name="remove"] {
  color: red;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: .2em;
  border: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}
<form id="dynamicForm">
  <fieldset name="list">
    <legend>List</legend>
    <fieldset name="input">
      <input type="text" name="inputField[]"><button type="button" name="remove" title="Remove input">✖</button>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
  <button type="button" name="add">Add Input</button>
</form>




Use the Forms and HTMLFormControlsCollection properties. In the example below checkboxes are used to select some, all, or none of the items for removal. Details are commented in example.


// Reference <form id="ui">
const ui = document.forms.ui;
/* 
  Reference all form controls in form#ui
  In this layout it is all:
    - <fieldset>
    - <output>
    - <input>
    - <button>
*/
const io = ui.elements;
// Reference <legend>
const title = io.main.firstElementChild;
// Reference <ul>
const list = document.querySelector("ul");

/**
 * This helper function checks to see if there any <li> in <ul> 
 * and reveals or hides <legend> and/or <button id="rem">
 * accordingly.
 */
const setMode = () => {
  if (list.childElementCount === 1) {
    title.classList.add("hidden");
    io.rem.classList.remove("hidden");
  } else if (list.childElementCount > 1) {
    title.classList.remove("hidden");
    io.rem.classList.remove("hidden");
  } else {
    title.classList.add("hidden");
    io.rem.classList.add("hidden");
  }
};
/* NOTE:
  Any mention of [select] is actually input[name=select] 
  (a checkbox in each <li>) which depending on the context 
  is singular or plural.
*/
/**
 * This event handler determines whether <button id="add"> 
 * or <button id="rem"> was clicked by the user and 
 * then adds or removes <li> from <ul>.
 * @param {object} e - Event object
 */
const clickHandler = e => {
  // The element the user clicked
  const clk = e.target;
  // If the user clicked button#add...
  if (clk == io.add) {
    // append htmlString to <ul>...
    const html = `
      <li>
        <input name="item[]">
        <input name="select" type="checkbox">
      </li>`;
    list.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", html);
  // Otherwise if the user clicked button#rem...
  } else if (clk == io.rem) {
    /*
      if there's only one <li> in <ul> AND [select] is
      checked...
    */
    if (list.childElementCount === 1 && io.select.checked) {
      // empty out <ul>...
      list.replaceChildren();
    /*
      otherwise collect all [select] into an array and 
      remove the <li> that contain [select] that are checked...
    */
    } else {
      const selects = Array.from(io.select);
      selects.forEach(chk => {
        if (chk.checked) {
          chk.parentElement.remove();
        }
      });
    }
    // Reset input#all and output#msg
    io.all.checked = false;
    io.msg.value = "Select All Items";
  /*
    Otherwise if neither <button> were clicked, terminate 
    this function.
  */
  } else {
    return;
  }
  /*
    Call setMode() to hide <legend> and/or button#rem 
    if necessary.
  */
  setMode();
};

/**
 * This event handler checks all [select] if input#all is 
 * checked and vice versa.
 * @param {object} e - Event object
 */
const toggleItems = e => {
  /*
    Gather all [select] into a HTMLCollection 
    (array-like object).
  */
  const selects = io.select;
  /*
    If #all is checked, check all [select] and change
    output#msg...
  */
  if (e.target.checked) {
    selects.forEach(chk => chk.checked = true);
    io.msg.value = "Deselect All Items";
  // otherwise uncheck all [select] and change output#msg
  } else {
    selects.forEach(chk => chk.checked = false);
    io.msg.value = "Select All Items";
  }
};

/*
  <form> calls clickHandler function when the "click"
  event fires.
*/
ui.addEventListener("click", clickHandler);

/*
  <input id="all" type="checkbox"> calls toggleItems 
  function when the "change" event is fired on it 
  (user un/checks it).
*/
io.all.addEventListener("change", toggleItems);
:root {
  font: 4vmax/1.2 "Segoe UI"
}

#main {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  width: min-content;
  min-height: 100vh;
}

#main fieldset {
  position: sticky;
  bottom: 0;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: min-content;
  padding-right: 0.25rem;
  padding-left: 0.25rem;
  background: white;
  translate: -0.75rem;
}

legend,
li {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

legend {
  margin-bottom: -0.5rem;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0
}

.hidden {
  display: none
}

input,
output,
button {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 12rem;
  font: inherit
}

[type='checkbox'] {
  width: 1rem;
  height: 1rem;
}

#all {
  translate: 0.25rem;
}
<form id="ui">
  <fieldset id="main">
    <legend class="hidden">
      <output id="msg">Select All Items </output>
      <input id="all" type="checkbox">
    </legend>
    <ul></ul>
    <fieldset>
      <button id="add" type="button">Add Item</button>
      <button id="rem" class="hidden" type="button">Remove Selected Items</button>
    </fieldset>
  </fieldset>
</form>




Your HTML and JS are correct. Did you forget the <script> and </script> tags needed around the JS?
HTML:
<form id="dynamicForm">
  <div id="inputContainer">
    <input type="text" name="inputField[]">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="addInput">Add Input</button>
  <button type="button" id="removeInput">Remove Input</button>
</form>

Scripts:
<script>
const addButton = document.getElementById('addInput');
const removeButton = document.getElementById('removeInput');
const inputContainer = document.getElementById('inputContainer');

addButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const newInput = document.createElement( 'input' );
  newInput.type = 'text';
  newInput.name = 'inputField[]';
  inputContainer.appendChild(newInput);
});

removeButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
  const inputs = inputContainer.getElementsByTagName( 'input' );
  if (inputs.length > 1) {
    inputContainer.removeChild(inputs[inputs.length - 1]);
  } else {
    alert('At least one input field is required!');
  }
});
</script>


Please describe proper details



let brArray=new Array();
let inputArr=new Array();
let saved=false;
let c=1;
let del=false;
let option="";
let enter=false;
let swap=false;
let y=[false,0];
let second=false;
let lp=false;
let warning=false; 
function deleteLast()
{
  let c1=c-1;
  let input=document.getElementById("input"+c1.toString());
  let br=document.getElementById("br"+c1.toString());
  //window.alert("input"+c1.toString());
  try
  {
    input.remove();
    br.remove();
    c--;
   }
   catch(err)
   {
   window.alert("There are no inputs to delete");
   }
}
function Addinput()
{
  //console.log(c);
  let d=0;
  let r=false;
  for(let i=1;i<inputArr.length;i++)
  {
    if(inputArr[i]=="empty")
    {
        r=true;
        d=i;
        i=inputArr.length;

    }
  }
    if(saved==false)
  {
    if(inputArr[c]!="empty" && r!=true)
    {
        let len=inputArr.length;
        let input=document.createElement("input");
        input.id="input"+c.toString();
        let br=document.createElement("br");
        br.id="br"+c.toString();
        document.getElementById("area").appendChild(input);
        document.getElementById("area").appendChild(br);
        inputArr[c]="input"+c.toString();
        brArray[c]="br"+c.toString();
        c++;

    }
    if(inputArr[d]=="empty" && r==true)
    {
        let len=inputArr.length;
        let input=document.createElement("input");
        input.id="input"+d.toString();
        let br=document.createElement("br");
        br.id="br"+d.toString();
        document.getElementById("area").appendChild(input);
        document.getElementById("area").appendChild(br);
        inputArr[d]="input"+d.toString();
        brArray[d]="br"+d.toString();

    } 
  }
}

function delinput()
{
    //console.log(inputArr);
   //console.log(lp+":lp");


    if(second==true)
  {

  }
  if(c>1)
  {
    enter=true;
    let cv=0;
    for(let i=1;i<inputArr.length;i++)
    {
        if(lp==true)
        {
            let inputVal=document.getElementById("inp").value;
            if(inputVal==inputArr[i])
            {
                lp=false;
                //console.log(inputVal+" "+inputArr[i]);
                warning=false;
            }
            else
            {
                //console.log(inputVal+" "+inputArr[i]);
                cv++;
            }
        }
    }
    if(cv==inputArr.length)
    {
        lp=true;
        window.alert("Please enter a correct ID to remove");
        warning=true;
    }

  }
  else
  {
    enter=false;
  }
 // console.log(del+" "+enter);
  if(del==false && enter==true)
  {
    let button=document.getElementById("Add");
    let inp=document.createElement("input");
    button.replaceWith(inp);
    inp.value="Enter the ID to Delete Here";
    inp.id="inp";
    inp.setAttribute("onclick","removeText()");
    let ids=document.createElement("p");
    ids.id="content";
    ids.innerHTML="Select from these ID's to delete: ";
    for(let i=1;i<c;i++)
    {
       if(inputArr[i]!="empty")
       {
            ids.innerHTML=ids.innerHTML+" "+inputArr[i];
       }
    }

    document.getElementById("area").appendChild(ids);
    document.getElementById("Delete").innerHTML="Click Again to Delete";
    del=true;
    second=false;

}
else if(enter==true && second==false)
{
    let inp=document.getElementById("inp").value;
    let counter=0;
    for(let i=1;i<c;i++)
    {
        if(inputArr[i]==inp)
        {
            let deleted=document.getElementById(inp);
            let br=document.getElementById(brArray[i]);
            br.remove();
            deleted.remove();
            y[1]=i;
            y[0]=true;

            del=false;
            inputArr[i]="empty";
            brArray[i]="empty";
            let content=document.getElementById("content");
            content.remove();  
        }
        else
        {
            counter++;
        }
    }
    //console.log(counter+":counter "+c+":c");
    if(counter==c-1 && warning==false)
    {
        window.alert("You have not entered a correct input");
        lp=true;
        second=false;
    }
    else
    {
        second=true;
        let button=document.createElement("button");
        button.id="Add";
        let inpA=document.getElementById("inp");
        inpA.replaceWith(button);
        button.setAttribute("onclick","Addinput()");
        button.innerHTML="Add Input";
        saved=false;
        document.getElementById("Delete").innerHTML="Delete Input";
    }



}  
//console.log(enter);
if(enter==false)
{
    window.alert("You have Not created any inputs to delete");
}

}
function removeText()
{
    let button=document.getElementById("inp");
   button.value="";
}
<button id="Add" onclick="Addinput()">Add Input</button>
<button id="Delete" onclick="delinput()">Search and Delete Input</button>
<button id="Del" onclick="deleteLast()">Delete last Input</button>
<div id="area">
</div>



The above code uses an array to store input ID's, it has a delete ID function with search criteria, a add input button and a delete last input button. The Input ID's automatically adjust based upon if there is a free slot in the input ID array and if there is not it fills up that empty slot. The user can search the ID of an input field and delete it. Once deleted the user can add another input field and the array counter will assign the input field a ID based on what is available within the array or will create a new ID for the input. The reason why Im using arrays to store the input ID's is because it makes it easier to find and delete them, by using a for loop. I go through the list of inputs and delete the specified one. Once deleted the deleted cell is given the value "empty". When I add another input i search for that "empty" value within the array and assign the input id based on how many cells the array has. Every time, you click add input. the counter increases and a new array element is added.
I use c++; to increase my array cells with the onclick function assigned to a button. When the for loop runs and a "empty" value is found i store the cell number and use it to add a new input in that "empty" cell

Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?

@trincot I added a add input button and a delete input button. I dont know if this is what you need. I really hope you can use some of this code in your project. Kind Regards. I will be happy to help with what i can. The way the browser handles the exchange of data after each click is hard to explain.

Can you reread the first comment and the part in bold? The idea is that your post contains details that explain the posted code and specifically how it answers the question. Please put this info in your post, not in a comment below it.

@trincot I hope that is better :)

Thanks for having edited it! It's better like this.
